# Why do I get "cannot move out of borrowed content" when using `for &item in`?

Tags: rust

I want to get the largest item in an array where largest is define in custom logic.

Here is an `i32` version that compiles

```
fn largest(list: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut largest = list[0];

    for &item in list.iter() {
        if item > largest {
            largest = item;
        }
    }

    largest
}
```

Here is a struct version that does not compile

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Point {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}
fn largestPoint(list: &[Point]) -> Point {
    // Defaulting to something
    let mut myPoint: Point = Point { x: 1.0, y: 1.0 };

    for &item in list.iter() {
        if (item.x > myPoint.x) {
            myPoint = item.clone();
        }
    }

    myPoint
}
```

What does this compiler error mean?

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:11:9
   |
11 |     for &item in list.iter() {
   |         ^----
   |         ||
   |         |hint: to prevent move, use `ref item` or `ref mut item`
   |         cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Isn't `.iter()` always a reference to the original list? How can I move the item through a reference?

Comment: [`list.iter().max()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max) / [`list.iter().max_by()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max_by) / [`list.iter().max_by_key()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max_by_key).

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for the suggestion, but I am very new in rust, and I want to understand the mechanic of ownership before using shortcuts

Comment: Sure, which is why it's a comment, not an answer. Have you read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/)? This is a pretty beginner question and most beginner questions are covered in the book.

Comment: Why have you chosen to use `for &item` instead of `for item`? Doing such solves your problem.

Comment: @Shepmaster I am currently studying chapter 10 right now, and the first largest implementation is provided in [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-00-generics.html) , I was just copying the implementation for `i32` but I know that since `i32` is primitive it has `Copy` and I wanted to implemented a struct version, I actually don't know why the author uses `&item` instead of just `item`

Comment: Unrelated advice: if your list is empty, there is no largest point, therefore your function should not return an arbitrary value. The idiomatic solution here is to return an `Option<Point>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for &item in list.iter() {
    if (item.x > myPoint.x) {
        myPoint = item.clone();
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't work because the `for` loop iterates over a set of references to items in the array of type `&Point`. When you bind this to `&item` you're trying to destructure the reference. This worked with the list of `i32` because `i32` implements `Copy` and so that item can just be copied but with the list of `Point`s it has to move ownership which isn't possible.

You can fix your code by changing `&item` to `item` like this.

```
for item in list.iter() {
    if (item.x > myPoint.x) {
        myPoint = item.clone();
    }
}
```

If that still isn't clear, consider this about this example.

```
for &(x, y) in [(1, 2), (2, 30)].iter() {
    println!("({}, {})", x, y);
}
```

Also take a look at the destructuring examples [at Rust by Example](https://rustbyexample.com/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_pointers.html).

Comment: Perhaps you could suggest how the OP could make their original code work?

Comment: this is confusing, because, if I don't use `&item` for object with `Copy` the function won't work. It will complain `^^^^ expected i32, found &i32`

Comment: If you change from `&item` to `item` in the first example, the type of `item` will change from `i32` to `&i32`. Now when you compare `item > largest`, you're comparing `&i32` to `i32` which gives you the error.

Comment: @Jal You need to write `*item` instead of `item` within the loop. This will dereference the `&i32` and yield an `i32`.